# Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() to create a new clomuns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble with my code, I wanted to create a new columns based on the result of an other but I got this error with this code

```
if t['t'] > 25 :
    t['Sup25'] = 1
else :
    t['Sup25'] = 0
```

It's very simple but I can't find why I got this

Thank you

I got this
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: What is returned for `t['t'] > 25` is a series of Boolean values (True or False) for each value in the column.  The answer below will convert the Boolean to integers and set the column `Sup25` to this converted series.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the result of the comparison directly to a new column. If you need it to be integer, just convert it to `int`:

```
t['Sup25'] = (t['t'] > 25).astype(int)
```